# Where is $f_x$ continuous for $f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2)/\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Question**

> Where is $f_x$ continuous for $f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2)/\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ for $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

**Issues**

My attempt to calculate the derivative gave me (using the 1D quotient rule)
$$ f_x = \frac{2x}{(x^2+y^2)} + \frac{2x}{3} \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$

Although in the solution to this, I see that the derivative is
$$f_x = \frac{2x}{3}\frac{2x^2+4y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^{4/3}}.$$

How does once achieve this form?? What are the steps that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

$$f_x = \frac{2x(x^2+y^2)^{1/3}-\frac23x(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)^{-2/3}}{(x^2+y^2)^{2/3}}=$$

$$=\frac{2x(x^2+y^2)-\frac23x(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{4/3}}=\frac{\frac43x^3+\frac83xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^{4/3}}=\frac23x\cdot\frac{2x^2+4y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{4/3}}$$

What you say they got seems to have a mistake with the power of $\;y\;$ in the numerator.